# How do I prevent javascript from passing by reference when passing in an object's child

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In my project there is a monochromatic screen you can write to and clear. Within the class I have these two lines of code for clearing the screen. the first pushes the current pixel values from the screen onto a stack so the clearscreen can be undone later. The second line clears the screen. the problem is that the undo stack is getting a reference to this.pixels rather than getting the value of it at the time.

```
this.pushUndo(this.pixels); //this.pixels is an array of ints
this.updateScreen(new Array(64*32)); //this.pixels changes at the end of this line but the undo stack shouldn't change its value
```

Comment: you can try cloning object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create a **shallow** copy:

```js
const pixels0 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const pixels1 = pixels0.slice(0);

// modify only index 0 of copy.
pixels1[0] = 1;

console.log(pixels0);
// expected output: Array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(pixels1);
// expected output: Array [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you need a **deep** copy, you can check [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

I usually do `Object.assign` when I need to clone values.
Example:

```
const clone = Object.assign([], yourArray);
```

Can you show what is inside the `updateScreen` method in your question?